# How to convert hashed result into readable format?

Tags: solidity, javascript

I'm trying to convert a hashed block number "30054a" into readable format but I'm getting logs something like this:

```
0J
```

For another hashed value:

```
Y����#�(�J�d��F,ĦJ/
```

I'm using the following code on my NodeJS server:

const util = require('ethjs-util');
const value = util.toAscii('30054a');
console.log(value);

I had even tried `toUtf8`. I'm using ethjs library.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You said the value is "hashed," but I think you're just looking at the hexadecimal number?

If so, `parseInt('30054a', '16') == 3147082`. 3147082 is the decimal representation of the hexadecimal number 0x30054a.

If you actually have a value that's been hashed, there's generally no way to reverse that process. (A cryptographic hash function is designed to be one-way.)

Comment: What about hexadecimal string, object or function?

Comment: I tried converting this cded53d631ce4a38a1f90d59e5f2f9c023cd28c64aa66488e9462cc4a64a032f using web3.toAscii(). It returned - ÍíSÖ1ÎJ8¡ù
YåòùÀ#Í(ÆJ¦déF,Ä¦J/

Comment: I didn't say anything about `web3.toAscii`. That would only be appropriate if the value you have came from an ASCII string. Where did those values come from?

Comment: I called the etherscan API of event logs. All the key's field are in hexadecimal format. How can I convert it in readable format?

Comment: Can you suggest any accurate article or course which explains the whole concept ot hexa to big number to whatever?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal might help. Do you mean the "topics" en the events? https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.23/contracts.html#events might help to understand what those are. You'll need to know the types of the parameters to interpret the values properly.